# Sending files from a GCP Storage Bucket to a Endpoint URL

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for a way to automatically export data stored in a GCP Storage Bucket to an Endpoint URL (https source).

The data I would like to export are Snowflake log files, which are copied into GCP storage following this guide:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-gcs.html

I would like to export these log files (csv or json) to a Sumo Logic https collector. I have seen a case where logs in the log explorer could be sent to a similar Endpoint URL using Logs Router + Pub/Sub.

What's the best way for me to do this?

Looked at Firebaes, Bigquery, and other GCP products, no solution found for my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think (!?) [Logs Router](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview) is only applicable to log entries (records) that are being sent to Google's Cloud Logging service.

IIUC in this case, Snowflake is emitting its log files directly to Cloud Storage and you want to trigger behavior based on these being created.

One way to trigger behavior based on changes to Cloud Storage buckets and objects is to use [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) with Cloud Functions.

I've not yet used [EventArc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/overview) but it's described as an event-driven mechanism and seems to be intended to become a more universal way (a broader set of events will be supported) to trigger actions. Cloud Storage is an event source for EventArc and -- IIUC -- you can use a Cloud Run service (but not Cloud Functions) as a target.

The [next-gen Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/introducing-the-next-generation-of-cloud-functions) platform deploys Cloud Function as Cloud Run services. So, if I were you (and, to reiterate, I've not built this for myself), I think I'd start trying to use EventArc with Cloud Run and, if that doesn't work, revert to Cloud Storage Triggers.